# How to fix jfoenix modules with javafx 11

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, java-module, jfoenix

So I'm adding my requires for module-info.java and finally got my program to load but as soon as tab pane wants to load from jfoenix library this error is thrown.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTabPaneSkin (in module com.jfoenix) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TabPaneBehavior (in module javafx.controls) because module javafx.controls does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior to module com.jfoenix
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way you can try fixing this is by adding the vm option for the required export:

```
--add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix
```

The ideal solution to that would be the `jfoenix` library to move away from using `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TabPaneBehavior`.

Comment: I added to vm option and I'm now getting Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTabPaneSkin$TabHeaderContainer (in module com.jfoenix) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler (in module javafx.controls) because module javafx.controls does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.control to module com.jfoenix

Answer (score 3):

I was able to successfully run every aspect of the jfoenix library thus far. I still have some testing to do in my application to make sure there are no errors hidden but at this moment the following VM options fixed the issue :

```
--add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix
--add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=com.jfoenix
--add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=com.jfoenix
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=com.jfoenix
--add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=com.jfoenix
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that if I'm using a module-info.java for my project?

Comment: folks if you still get error try adding this ```--add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=com.jfoenix```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to all this module pain is to completely abandon the JPMS and put all libraries (also JavaFX) on the classpath and then start your application via a launcher like this:

```
class MyAppLauncher {public static void main(String[] args) {MyApp.main(args);}}
```

Comment: Note that, while this will likely work for most JavaFX apps running on JavaFX 11-17 (and is way easier than dealing with JPMS modules), running JavaFX on the classpath isn't a configuration supported by the JavaFX development team, so this approach is not guaranteed to work for new JavaFX release (and, for recent JavaFX releases, will generate a warning at runtime, then continue to happily execute).

Comment: If they ever make that really fail this will be the day when I quit supporting and using JavaFX. I have better things to do than spending my time fighting with the module system.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it works for me. I hope it will be useful for you too.

```
--module-path "D:\Libs\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib"  
--add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics
--add-opens javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED
```