# How to integrate Jfoenix with eclipse

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

Hi everyone I'm new to JavaFx, I recently started learning it and I managed to include it in eclipse without any problems.
The only problem I am facing right now is JFoenix library. Whenever I add this latter to the module path and import some modules in my own one an error arises that says :`com.jfoenix.controls cannot be resolved to a module`

Can some one show me in details how to fix this in eclipse?

I'm currently using JDK-16 ,JavaFX-16, jfoenix-9.0.10 and the latest version of eclipse

Comment: Related, perhaps a duplicate: [How to fix jfoenix modules with javafx 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037442/how-to-fix-jfoenix-modules-with-javafx-11)

Comment: I've seen this post already but it didn't help at all

Comment: It is always good to link to previous research you have done for a question when you ask it.