# How to run a javaFx program

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, virtual-machine, fxml

> class com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTabPaneSkin (in unnamed module @0x7f6b9ff9) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TabPaneBehavior (in module javafx.controls) because module javafx.controls does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior to unnamed module @0x7f6b9ff9

So I ran a program with this error, i don't know the way to solve this error. Is there somebody can help me, please?

I added some lines into the VM options in IntelliJ IDE, but it's not working.

Comment: Some useful information related to creating and running a JavaFX application - [Create a new JavaFX project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html)

Comment: Do a Google search for **java platform module system**

Comment: JFoenix is not maintained.  Additionally, older versions of JFoenix are not built to function correctly with modern JavaFX versions.  If you *need* similar functionality beyond the standard JavaFX controls, consider [MaterialFX](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX) instead.

Comment: Hello, please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/53037601/20979453, it seems the same problem as yours.

Answer (score 0):

**Preface:**

You do NOT need to pass any vm arguments. Just download and Run the main method of the launcher class.

Note: The projects contain an action to create an executable fat JAR.

**Solution 1:**

Download this preconfigured project template and edit it to your needs:

*Example working JavaFX application with gradle:*
https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxAppGradleNonModular

*Example working JavaFX application with maven:*
https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxAppMavenNonModular

**Solution 2:**

You need at least JDK17 installed.

Generated a runnable preconfigured project with this generator:

https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxProjectGenerator

*Direkt Downloadlink of the generator:* https://wedasoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/JavaFxProjectGenerator-1.4.1.jar

*Homepage:* https://wedasoft.com/projects/javafx-project-generator/